# Javascript snippet not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm using Tigra calendar (https://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/) in my code as a simple pop-up calendar with any input text, but I'm facing some kind of problem that's driving me nuts.

To use this calendar, it's just needed to add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
```

in the head section, and add class="tcal" to the input

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="" />
```

Working demo in https://jsfiddle.net/fgh7yjg7/

But now, using the same calendar inside a Bootstrap3 modal, it simply doesn't work in my code (although it does in a simple modal sample with jsfiddle)

What could be wrong?

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: No one, buddy. I have also checked changing the links to tcal.css and tcal.js before the </body> (although the programmer said that must be linked in head section) and still nothing

Comment: The calender plugin runs on pageload, catching all elements with a certain class, and altering them. It doesn't catch elements that are added dynamically later. You have to call the plugin again after the elements are loaded, and as this is a company that sells the calender software, and doesn't seem to have much documentation online, you'll probably have to contact the company.

Comment: Add defer attribute to your script tag like `<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js" defer></script>` Also I checked the source and depending on your browser uses `attachEvent()` instead of `addEventListener()` and at some places it uses the `onclick` property for the td elements which might get overwritten with slight possibility.

Comment: Still not working after your suggestions, but thank you all anyway. I'll try to contact the programmers (although it looks like there's no recent activity from them)